# Open "About This Mac" window

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

How can I display **About This Mac** window?

I know that it is managed by the `loginwindow` process so I tried to open in applescript(I'm still a beginner).

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "loginwindow"
    open window "About This Mac"
end tell
```

The code keeps on running. It neither stops nor displays window nor shows any error. Is it even right command?

So, how can I open **About This Mac** window?

The solution is not limited to applescript. Is there a way to open it from terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the applescript but I know how to do it terminal.

Use `open` command in the Terminal to open **About This Mac** window.

```
open -a "About This Mac"
```

Comment: The application `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/About This Mac.app` is only available on macOS Sierra, so your answer fails on versions of OS X prior to macOS Sierra.

Comment: @user3439894 I too just realised. Is there any way to open it prior macOS Sierra then?

Comment: @SkrewEverything, If one is running macOS Sierra, then your answer if fine.

Answer (score 4):

The application `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/About This Mac.app` is only available on macOS Sierra, so 
SkrewEverything's answer fails on versions of OS X prior to macOS Sierra.

Here is an example of AppleScript code to open "About This Mac" via UI Scripting:

```
tell application "System Events" to click menu item "About This Mac" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "Finder"
```

The above AppleScript *command* can be executed in Terminal using `osascript` as in the example below:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to click menu item "About This Mac" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "Finder"'
```

Note that when using UI Scripting, the calling application will need to be given permission for assistive access by adding the target app to, e.g.: System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility